# how to write a test to match for data in array within postman test

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have created a variable called values, this value contains an array below:

`var values = ["A","B", "C","D","E","F"]`

I want to write a test to match json response data to one of the values in values.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("risk check", function () { 
pm.expect(jsonData.result.value).is.to.equal(values);  
});
```

The data in response result.value can only be A, B, C, D, E, F

```
{
   "result":{
      "score":{
         "value":"F"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [oneOf](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) method from the Chaijs library:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("risk check", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.result.score.value).to.be.oneOf(values);  
});
```

This should then check to the values in the array against the response from the endpoint and will fail if it doesn't match.

Comment: Doesn't 'values' have to be inside an array?

Comment: `values` is an array, take a look at the original question 